# Neo4J is it ok to use two create statements in the same query?

Tags: neo4j

I couldn't find documentation about it anywhere, but I need to build a query that should create a new node and 3 new relationships between that node and other existing ones.
So, I used one create statement to create two relationships, and then another beneath to create the third.
So, is it correct to use two and more create statements, or is there a better way to achieve it?
My code:

```
match (p1:Person{name:'David'})
match (movie:Movie{title:'Harry Potter'})
create (p1)-[:KNOWS]->(p2:Person{name:'Ronald'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
create (p2)-[:KNOWS]->(p1)
return p1, p2, movie
```

Comment: it's fine, there's no restriction on the limit of `CREATE` or `MERGE` statements to be present in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ok to use multiple "CREATE" statements in the same query. In the [Cypher Refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/), under the "Write-only query structure" section, you can see:

> *(CREATE | MERGE)**

which means: zero (or more) "CREATE" or "MERGE" statements is allowed